# R - create new column dataframe based on index of value match with existing column

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I have a dataframe called `imp2` (with about 6,000 rows) for which there are 9 columns labeled `'savres1'...'savres9'`. Values in each of these columns are either 1 or 0. For each row, the value of only 1 of these columns is 1 (rest are 0).

I'd like to create a new column called `'savres'` into which I would put a value between 1 and 9 that matches the index of the column (within this set of 9 columns) which holds the 1 value. E.g. if `'savres7'` is 1 and the rest of these columns are 0, then `savres` should equal 7.

I've used several variations of `which`, `match` and `%in%` to find the value, but I'm not getting the output I expect.

Below is a recent trial function and a sample set of rows that are created in the dataframe.

Recent attempted solution:

```
imp2 <- within(imp2, savres <- which(c(savres1, savres2, savres3, savres4, savres5, savres6, savres7, savres8, savres9) == 1) %% 9 + 1)
```

Results:

(Note, I didn't include all columns, but from the 4 here, you can see that the function isn't working - the `'savres'` value in row 4 should be 3 and those for rows 1 and 2  should not be 4 or 2)

```
sample <- head(imp2[c('savres1','savres2','savres3','savres4')],4)

savres | savres1 | savres2 | savres3 | savres4
4      |     0   |    0    |    0    |    0
2      |   0     |    0    |    0    |    0
1      |   1     |    0    |    0    |   0
1      |   0     |   0     |  1      |   0
```

Can anyone recommend a solution?

I thought this should be a fairly simple operation, but I've been frustrated with a number of approaches I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max.col`

```
i1 <- grep("^savre", names(df1))
transform(df1, savre = (max.col(df1[i1], "first"))* !!rowSums(df1[i1]))
#    col1 col2 savres1 savres2 savres3 savres4 savre
#1    1    2       0       0       0       0     0
#2    2    3       0       0       0       0     0
#3    3    4       1       0       0       0     1
#4    4    5       0       0       1       0     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:4, col2 = 2:5, savres1 = c(0, 0, 1,0), 
   savres2 = 0, savres3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1), savres4 = 0)
```

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi  Yes, it is `startsWith(names(df1), "savres")`

Comment: @Scott Yes you can assign it as `df1$savre <- (max.col(df1[i1], "first"))* !!rowSums(df1[i1])`

Comment: you're a godsend - thank you so much. With some minor modifications, this approach worked like a charm. I ultimately decided to directly place the values in dataframe rather than use transform, which took longer to process and created some issues. Final code: `i1 <- grep("^savres", names(imp2))
imp2$save.reason <- (max.col(imp2[i1], "first"))* !!rowSums(imp2[i1])`

Comment: @Scott Thank you for the comments.  I am glad that I was able to help you.

Comment: Thanks again :thumbs_up

Comment: also, out of curiosity i had a quick question about the `* !!rowSums(df1[i1])` component of the snippet. It seems like we should be fill the column with the correct index value with `(max.col(df1[i1], "first"))` alone. I've also tried this more minimal and it seems functional. Is there something that I'm missing here? What does `!!rowSums` add for us?

Comment: @Scott It is just for cases where there are only 0's in a particular row.  The `rowSums` return 0 for those rows, by negating it, all other values becomes FALSE and 0 becomes TRUE, so we double negate to make the 0 as FALSE and multiplying by it, so that it coerce to binary and we get 0 for those rows that have only 0

Comment: Gotcha - very smart approach. Makes sense, and covers a case I should have considered